# Apple ID scam, gave control of my computer for a few minutes

Tags: macos, security, terminal, phishing

I was called from what appears to be a legitimate apple phone number and i was told there was suspicious activity. Then I said I wanted to speak to someone and I was connected to a someone with an Indian accent. This person made me type `www.fastsupport.com\apple` into the run command and I installed something that gave this person control of my computer, similar to teamviewer.

I got an email from `apple.care@techie.com` which was in the spam folder and the guy opened `netstat` in the terminal and told me some stuff I didn’t understand. Then he did something which started bunch of lines appearing on the command line. At that point I got spooked and closed the terminal and the connection.

What might be compromised, what should I be doing now?

Comment: Phone numbers can be spoofed, back up your data and reinstall your OS.

Comment: Pretty much no one can know what they did.  It could be benign probes and checks or something sinister like a back door.  @Moab solution is really the correct one.

Comment: @Moab for example can the saved passwords on chrome or other apps be stolen?

Comment: Yes, anything can be done, depends on the app whether it protects passwords by encrypting them or storing them in plain text.

Comment: You should assume everything vital was compromised, and you should take steps to secure that information, the purpose of connecting to your machine was to steal important information.  Apple will never call you, unless you have arranged for a phone call, and they certainly will NEVER use the remote solution you used.

Comment: Was this in macOS? If so open up Terminal (what you are calling `cmd` but that is a Windows thing; macOS uses the Terminal) and type in `history`. That should show you the command history run from the Terminal including stuff the scammers typed in. That said, you should definitely assumed anything personal on that computer has been compromised. I would recommend changing every password you have to pretty much everything.

Answer (score 2):

It's true you "might", but you should assume you are.

So the only correct thing to do now is to back up your data and fully reinstall your OS.

You should this before doing anything else on your computer. Do you open your email, do not access your bank, do not open your password manager or any other personal or sensitive data.

Then you should change ALL your passwords.